# How to read file sent from curl to Flask?

Tags: python, curl, flask

Flask code -

```
 @app.route('/messages', methods = ['POST'])
 def api_message():

    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/plain':
       return "Text Message: " + request.data

    elif request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
        f = open(filename,'r')
        l = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        return len(l)
```

On running, I get error as -

```
curl -H  "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/messages --data filename=@hello.json 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Am I accessing the curl param wrong (filename)? Or I am sending the file in wrong way?

Also [Upload a file to a python flask server using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329087/upload-a-file-to-a-python-flask-server-using-curl)

Tried doing

```
   f = request.files['filename']
```

Still, same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your `curl` command code is doing is reading the file `hello.json` and putting it in the body of the request. (This feature is actually very useful if you have a large chunk of JSON you need to send to the server).

Normally in `application/json` requests you send the JSON as the body of the request, so this *may be* what you want. You can use [request.get_json](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Request.get_json) to get this data as a Python dictionary.

If you want to upload an **actual** file - like uploading a picture - you want multi part form encoding, which you tell curl to send via the `-F` parameter. (See also: an SO answer about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12667839/224334 ).

Comment: Problem arose because I had filename=@hello.json in curl.

curl -H  "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/messages --data @hello.json  

and request.get_json seems to solve the issue. 

Thank you so much!