# Unable to read text file data sent from curl to flask server

Tags: php, python, curl, flask

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471062/how-to-read-file-sent-from-curl-to-flask), but it is not relevant to my question, so thought I would ask this here.

I am sending a simple text file that contains the words **`HELLO WORLD`** using a PHP curl script to a python flask server:

```
<?php

$url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/transaction';
$ch = curl_init($url);
$cfile = ['file_contents' => curl_file_create ('sampledata.txt')];

$data = array('test_file' => $cfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Flask code:

```
@app.route('/transaction', methods=['POST'])
def read_file():
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        return request.data
    else:
        abort(500)
```

This gives an `HTTP 200` status code on the Flask terminal, but on the terminal where I execute the PHP script, it says: `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\..path..\testscript.php on line 9`

(Line 9 happens to be where I set the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data` option)

How do I output to screen the contents of the text file in this scenario?